# Comparing Values in One DataTable Column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable that I read in from a csv. What I would like to do is find all the duplicate names within one row titled "name" and add them to another datable for use later. The code I have so far:

```
private DataTable MatcherTable(DataTable table)
    {

        DataTable match = new DataTable();

        match = table.Clone();

        var equalRows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(dataRow => dataRow["name"] == dataRow["name"]).ToList();

        foreach (var equalRow in equalRows)
        {
            match.Rows.Add(equalRow.ItemArray);
        }

        return match;
    }
```

However when I return the table that should be full of matches, it returns the exact same table that I read in. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: _dataRow["name"] == dataRow["name"]_ you are comparing the same column from the same row. The expression is always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is simply copying all the datarows in the output table because the comparison expression compares the same row and column with itself.

You could resolve your problem with a single Linq expression

```
private DataTable MatcherTable(DataTable table)
{
    DataTable match = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                           .GroupBy(x => x["Name"])
                           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                           .Select(k => k.FirstOrDefault())
                           .CopyToDataTable();
    return match;
}
```

Here we GroupBy the rows using the value in the Name column and filter out all Groups with an occurence count less than 2. Next we take the first row from the group and build a Datarow sequence finally copied in the output table.

The code above will return just one row of the duplicate ones. If you want to keep all duplicate rows  then you need

```
    DataTable match = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                           .GroupBy(x => x["Name"])
                           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                           .SelectMany(k => k)
                           .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: This works great! Is there any way to retain the duplicates? I want to pull where the name matches but retain the data in the columns that follow for each duplicate. So if I have the same name 4 times, they will all have different values in the succeeding columns that I'd like to keep.

Comment: You just need to remove the FirstOrDefault and change Select to SelectMany

Answer (score 0):

Create empty List, so u can do this

```
List<string> names= new List<string>();
foreach(var row in table.Rows)
{
  if(names.Contains(row["name"])
  {
  names.Add(row["name"].ToString());
  }
else
{
   DataRow dr = match.NewDataRow();
   dr.ItemArray=row.ItemArray; match.Rows.Add(dr);
}
}
```

I might have some mistakes in spelling or smt, but this is just to give u an idea!